# Android Imageview and Buttons in the same View

Tags: android, button, layout, imageview

I have a Button and a ImageView on the same "Page". Now, I made a OnClickListener and when I Click the Button the Page clears and my Drawing appears. I think I have to change the setContentView(meinView) but I don't know how ?
I want when I click the Button that the Drawing will be made in the ImageView on the same "Page". I'm new in android-programming and I'm not sure that the xml-File is correct. It was made from the Android Studio 3.5.3.

The XML-File:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="422dp"
    android:layout_height="452dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="296dp"
    android:background="#555555"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="253dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="166dp"
        android:onClick="BeimKlick"
        android:text="Klick mich" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="109dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="514dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Main-Activity:

```
MeinView meinView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    meinView = new MeinView(this);
    meinView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final ProgressBar progressbar1 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    final ImageView iView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(meinView);
            //setContentView(R.id.imageView);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my Drawing-Class:

```
  int x;
  for (x=0;x<=200;x+=5)
  {
     canvas.drawLine(x, 0, x, 1000, paint);
  }
  int y;
  for (y=0;y<=200;y+=5)
  {
     canvas.drawLine(0, y, 1000, y, paint);
  }
  canvas.scale(6, 6);
  paint.setColor(Color.RED);
  canvas.drawText("Test", 20, 50, paint);
  canvas.drawText("Row1", 20, 70, paint);
  canvas.drawText("Row2", 20, 90, paint);
```

---

OK I used Framelayout instead of Relativelayout, but the same result as before. The controls (buttons/progressbar etc.) disappear and the drawing can be seen. Also I changed ImageView in SurfaceView but the same result (because I think ImageView is maybe not up-to-date anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Use `FrameLayout` for overlapping in your `XML` instead of `RelativeLayout`.